# How to determine whether a function is odd or even in a positive domain

Tags: functions

We know that a function f is even if $f(-x)=f(x)$ and odd if $f(-x)=-f(x)$.
Now my question : if the domain of the function is positive number, then how can I determine whether it odd or even?

For example:    determine whether the following function is odd or even.
$$f(x)=x(10-x), 0<x<10$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to ask if a function is odd/even when the domain of definition isn't symmetric around the origin.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer (+1)

Comment: You could define something similar: odd/even around $x=5$ (which would be the same as the function $f(x+5)$ being odd/even in the usual sense).